# Upload document on iCloud drive using node JS

Tags: node.js, icloud

I am working on an application that allows the user to login into an Apple account and access iCloud drive, I am also allowing the user to upload all documents on iCloud drive. Does Apple provide any open API to upload documents on the iCloud drive? Or Any node package which allows uploading the document on the iCloud drive?

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you have tried? The way you presented this question makes it look like you have not done enough research yourself. On searching on Google, I found this thread on [CloudKit Node JS Client](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/5232). Tell us what you hae tried so we do not give you duplicate answers

Comment: Thanks @orimdominic for help here. I have gone through all these links but I think you are missing the core part of my questions which is uploading documents on iCloud. There are libraries available for node https://github.com/MauriceConrad/iCloud-API, But these libraries doesn't support upload file functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the iCloud drive API is publicly available for developers right now. But instead of it you can use CloudKit API, it allows you to query on your iCloud data. You can use CloudKit provided CloudKit JS library in your Node application.
Go through this documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkitjs

Comment: That's not the same at all.